# Seed and clusterApply - how to select a specific run?

Tags: r, parallel-processing, k-means

I am performing k-means on a large dataset (636,688 rows x 7 columns) and have therefore turned to parallelization. My results need to be reproducible. I can do this using the `clusterSetRNGStream` from the `parallel` package. Here is an example using the `Boston` dataset from the `MASS` library:

```
library(parallel)
cl <- makeCluster(detectCores())
clusterSetRNGStream(cl, iseed = 1234)
clusterEvalQ(cl, library(MASS))
results <- clusterApply(cl, rep(25, 4), function(nstart) kmeans(Boston, 4, nstart = nstart))
check.results <- sapply(results, function(result) result$size)
stopCluster(cl)
```

Each `check.results` column represents the number of observations per respective cluster for a given run-through of the k-means algorithm. My `check.results` then looks like this:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]   38  268  102  102
[2,]  268   98   98   38
[3,]   98  102   38  268
[4,]  102   38  268   98
```

If I change my `results` variable to include `rep(25, 2)` instead of `rep(25, 4)`, I get:

```
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   38  268
[2,]  268   98
[3,]   98  102
[4,]  102   38
```

Perfect - the first 2 runs' sizes remain the same, regardless of me running 4 iterations or only 2. If you continue changing the number of iterations, you will see that each individual run remains the same.

**My question - how can I pick out e.g. the 4th run specifically without having to run the first 3 runs? Are there specific seeds saved under the underlying** `iseed` **in** `clusterSetRNGStream`**?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `clusterSetRNGStream` function doesn't support the kind of reproducibility that you want very well. The problem is that it simply initializes each of the cluster workers to draw random numbers from a different stream of random numbers which is reproducible when using clusterApply with a given number of workers. But to execute a particular task, you would have to execute it on the correct worker in order to get the correct stream, and fast forward in that stream, which isn't supported even if you know the exact number of random numbers consumed by each task.

Instead, I suggest that you use the lower level functions to assign a different substream of random numbers to each task. You can do that by generating the task seeds using the `nextRNGSubStream` function:

```
library(parallel)
# This is based on the clusterSetRNGStream function from
# the parallel package, copyrighted by The R Core Team
getseeds <- function(ntasks, iseed) {
  RNGkind("L'Ecuyer-CMRG")
  set.seed(iseed)
  seeds <- vector("list", ntasks)
  seeds[[1]] <- .Random.seed
  for (i in seq_len(ntasks - 1)) {
    seeds[[i + 1]] <- nextRNGSubStream(seeds[[i]])
  }
  seeds
}
```

Since we're not using `clusterSetRNGStream`, you need to set the random number generator to "L'Ecuyer-CMRG" when initializing the workers:

```
cl <- makeCluster(detectCores())
clusterEvalQ(cl, { library(MASS); RNGkind("L'Ecuyer-CMRG") })
```

The key is to set the value of ".Random.seed" from the worker function in order to use the correct random number substream for each task:

```
worker <- function(nstart, seed, centers=4) {
  assign(".Random.seed", seed, envir=.GlobalEnv)
  kmeans(Boston, centers, nstart = nstart)
}
```

Since we're iterating over both the `nstart` and `seed` values, you use `clusterMap` rather than `clusterApply` to execute the tasks:

```
n <- 4
nstarts <- rep(25, n)
seeds <- getseeds(n, 1234)
results <- clusterMap(cl, worker, nstarts, seeds)
```

To reproduce the results of the fourth task, you specify the fourth seed:

```
itasks <- c(4)
results <- clusterMap(cl, worker, nstarts[itasks], seeds[itasks])
```

Using this method, you get reproducible results even when load balancing via the `clusterMap` `.scheduling="dynamic"` argument since the results aren't dependent on the worker that executes the task as they are when using `clusterSetRNGStream`.

---

Note that you can use the `clusterMap` `MoreArgs` argument to specify a value for the `centers` argument of the `worker` function:

```
results <- clusterMap(cl, worker, nstarts, seeds, MoreArgs=list(centers=5))
```

Comment: @Anna I generalized the example to allow different values of centers to be specified.

Comment: Thank you! Very helpful. Also see https://rpubs.com/Jouni_Helske/225931 for further discussion